# Convert span tag to textbox with value inside it

Tags: jquery, html

I am going to make the editing the fields. When user click on edit i want information to converted into textbox with the value that was previously but i am getting problem. Below codes are what i have tried. It gives HTML tags instead of displaying the textbox. How can i achieve this. Thank you.

### Jquery

```
  $(".edit").on('click',function(){
    var name = $("#name").text();
    var city = $("#city").text();
    var mob = $("#mob").text();
    var x = '<input type="text" value="' + name + '">';
   $("#name").text(x);
   $("#city").text("<input type='text' value='" + city + "'>");
   $("#mob").text("<input type='text' value='" + mob + "'>");
});
```

### HTML

```
 <li class="list-group-item"> <b>Name:</b> <span class="inf" id="name">Some name</span> <span class="label label-info edit">Edit</span> </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> <b>Current City:</b> <span class="inf" id="city"> City name</span>  </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> <b>Mobile Number:</b> <span class="inf" id="mob"> mobile number </span> </li>
```

Comment: Why does your 'HTML' have php in it? If this is JavaScript, show the rendered HTML (as seen by the browser) php is irrelevant.

Comment: Text there is from database so i forgot to edit. Okey i am editing the question.

Comment: This may break if you enter values that have `<` or `>` characters in them.

Comment: @Ja͢ck then how can i handle those errors or is there any other way of dealing with my logics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .html() not .text()

```
$(".edit").on('click',function(){
    var name = $("#name").text();
    var city = $("#city").text();
    var mob = $("#mob").text();
    var x = '<input type="text" value="' + name + '">';
    $("#name").html(x);
    $("#city").html("<input type='text' value='" + city + "'>");
    $("#mob").html("<input type='text' value='" + mob + "'>");
});
```

since you want an html element to be seen on a specific element use `.html()`

Comment: oh such a silly mistake. I didn't takecare of the property. THank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

HTML:

```
<li class="list-group-item"> <b>Name:</b> <br/><span class="inf" id="name"><?php echo $uinfo->name; ?></span>  </li>
<li class="list-group-item"> <b>Current City:</b><br/> <span class="inf" id="city"><?php echo $uinfo->current_city; ?></span>  </li>
<li class="list-group-item"> <b>Mobile Number:</b><br/> <span class="inf" id="mob"><?php echo $uinfo->m_number; ?></span> </li><br/>
<span class="label label-info edit">Edit</span>
```

JS:

```
$(".edit").on('click',function(){
    var name = $("#name").text();
    var city = $("#city").text();
    var mob = $("#mob").text();
   $("#name").html("<input type='text' value='" + name + "'>");
   $("#city").html("<input type='text' value='" + city + "'>");
   $("#mob").html("<input type='text' value='" + mob + "'>");
});
```

Here the live [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vengatesh/c9L03qxd/) for your reference

Answer (score 0):

use **[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** in jquery ,and change attribute ,values,id

```
$(".edit").on('click', function () {
    $(".inf").each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith(function (i, text) {
            return $("<input>", { // change the type
                type: "text",
                value: text, // getting span text 
                id: this.id // getting span id
            })
        });
    });
});
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xtz111q3/3/)**